# Is it possible to display multiple screens in a loop in cobol?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

So I'm trying to make a program in [OpenCobolIDE](https://github.com/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE/) that uses the `SCREEN SECTION` feature in COBOL to create a menu where the user chooses whether he wants to input data or display it.
This data is being recorded in a sequential .txt file. The writing process works fine so I don't add the code of this part here. The problem is in the reading process. I wanted the program to display multiple times the `DISPLAY-SCREEN` in a `PERFORM` loop showing all the records in my file but this is not working. I thought that by removing the `BLANK SCREEN` from my `DISPLAY-SCREEN` it would work the way I wanted but all that happens is that the program shows the `DISPLAY-SCREEN` a single time and it doesn't even display any records. What could be the problem? Here is the code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID.PGM001.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.

FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT MYFILE ASSIGN TO "DATA.TXT"
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.
DATA DIVISION.

FILE SECTION.
FD MYFILE.
01 FS-TB.
    02 FS-ID    PIC X(03).
    02 FS-NAME  PIC A(15).
    02 FS-PHONE PIC X(09).
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 WS-TB.
    02 WS-ID    PIC X(03).
    02 WS-NAME  PIC A(15).
    02 WS-PHONE PIC X(09).
01 WS-EOF       PIC A(01) VALUE "N".
01 WS-COUNT     PIC 9(01) VALUE ZERO.
01 WS-OP        PIC 9(01).
SCREEN SECTION.
01 MENU-SCREEN.
    02 BLANK SCREEN.
    02 LINE 1  COL 1  VALUE "------------------------------------".
    02 LINE 2  COL 1  VALUE "-              MENU                -".
    02 LINE 3  COL 1  VALUE "------------------------------------".
    02 LINE 4  COL 1  VALUE "-          (1).REGISTER            -".
    02 LINE 5  COL 1  VALUE "-          (2).DISPLAY             -".
    02 LINE 6  COL 1  VALUE "-          (3).EXIT                -".
    02 LINE 7  COL 1  VALUE "-                                  -".
    02 LINE 8  COL 1  VALUE "           OPTION:( )              -".
    02 LINE 9  COL 1  VALUE "------------------------------------".
    02 LINE 8  COL 20 PIC 9(01) TO WS-OP.
01 DISPLAY-SCREEN.
    02 LINE 1  COL 1  VALUE "------------------------------------".
    02 LINE 2  COL 1  VALUE "-            DISPLAY               -".
    02 LINE 3  COL 1  VALUE "------------------------------------".
    02 LINE 4  COL 1  VALUE "-(1).ID         :                  -".
    02 LINE 4  COL 18 PIC X(03) FROM WS-ID.
    02 LINE 5  COL 1  VALUE "-(2).NAME       :                  -".
    02 LINE 5  COL 18 PIC A(15) FROM WS-NAME.
    02 LINE 6  COL 1  VALUE "-(3).PHONE      :                  -".
    02 LINE 6  COL 18 PIC X(09) FROM WS-PHONE.
    02 LINE 7  COL 1  VALUE "------------------------------------". 
PROCEDURE DIVISION.
A-100.
    DISPLAY MENU-SCREEN.
    ACCEPT  MENU-SCREEN.

    EVALUATE WS-OP
    WHEN 1
        GO TO A-200
    WHEN 2
        GO TO A-300
    WHEN 3
        STOP RUN
    WHEN OTHER
        GO TO A-100
    END-EVALUATE.
A-200.
A-300.
    OPEN INPUT MYFILE
        PERFORM UNTIL WS-EOF = "Y"
            READ MYFILE INTO WS-TB
                AT END MOVE "Y" TO WS-EOF
                NOT AT END DISPLAY DISPLAY-SCREEN
            END-READ
        END-PERFORM
    CLOSE MYFILE.

    STOP RUN.
END PROGRAM PGM001.
```

Comment: Put an ACCEPT after your DISPLAY. The screen is just too fast for you to see, then reverts to your "command line"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Bill pointed out already: The `PERFORM` and `DISPLAY` is too fast.

To see every record you´d need to add an `ACCEPT` after the `DISPLAY`, I guess `ACCEPT OMITTED` will work, if not add a dummy var and `ACCEPT` this.

You seem to not want to stop the program during the `PERFORM` then you may add an `ACCEPT DUMMY` at the program's end (always useful if you use extended `DISPLAY/ACCEPT`). But you would only get the last item displayed.

Depending on your needs a `CALL 'CBL_OC_NANOSLEEP' USING 500000000` (wait one-half second) or `CALL 'C$SLEEP' USING 1` after the `DISPLAY DISPLAY-SCREEN` may be the result you want.

But likely the best option would be `ACCEPT dummy WITH TIMEOUT time` (if you press ENTER it goes directly to the next `DISPLAY` if you don't it will wait the specified time before doing the next `DISPLAY`.

Comment: I've tried putting an ACCEPT after the DISPLAY DISPLAY-SCREEN but it ended up displaying only the first record. I don't know if i coded the way you meant. it looks something like this: NOT AT END DISPLAY DISPLAY-SCREEN ACCEPT DUMMY

Comment: @LeviMoraes Yes that is exactly what I've mentioned as option 1 - it will halt after the first record until you press enter, then again after the second, then ... - if you think this doesn't work copy the whole program, only include the `READ` part in and directly `DISPLAY record UPON SYSOUT` - it should output the same (only without the pause from `ACCEPT`). Option b leads to all records displayed with a adjustable pause and automatic next display.

Better: (I'll add this option to the first one) would be `ACCEPT WITH TIMEOUT`.

Comment: The TIMEOUT clause is not being recognized by the compiler, maybe i've screwed up in the syntax. Is this correct:ACCEPT dummy WITH TIMEOUT 1000? And when i have to press enter to accept the dummy variable it appears an annoying "0" in the first line. How can i take it away?. And also, is there anyway to show all the records at once displaying the screen multiple times instead of pressing a button to go to the next screen with the following records?

Comment: @LeviMoraes Your original question should include the exact version of the compiler you use. You should be able to see this in the about Dialog in the tab GnuCOBOL. OpenCOBOL 1.1 supported `ACCEPT dummy WITH TIMEOUT time` (with time being a positive numeric literal or identifier), too.
If DUMMY is a `PIC X` item there shouldn't be any strange zero anywhere, but you may want to use `ACCEPT dummy AT ... WITH AUTO TIMEOUT` for positioning it and removing the need for the enter (another key will work too).

Comment: @LeviMoraes if you want to `DISPLAY` multiple records at once you either need multiple fields in your screen or display them without using a screen entry with fixed line/col clauses (just display the records).